# MySQL order by number of substring occurrences

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, substring

Example table:

```
ID Name
1  Apple: Color: Yellow
2  Apple: Color: Red
3  Grapes: Color: Green
4  Grapes: Color: Green
5  Oranges: Color: Orange
6  Apple: Color: Yellow
7  Apple: Color: Yellow
```

I need to order it by number of fruits descending, without looking at the colors. I know the table could have been divided on fruits and colors, but thats another story.

Result should be something like this, ordered by the count of substring, "everything before the first :"

```
ID Name
1  Apple: Color: Yellow
2  Apple: Color: Red
6  Apple: Color: Yellow
7  Apple: Color: Yellow
3  Grapes: Color: Green
4  Grapes: Color: Green
5  Oranges: Color: Orange
```

Is it possible in mysql, or do I need to do the sorting in PHP f.ex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql> SELECT e.* FROM example AS e 
JOIN (
  SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ':', 1) AS fruit, count(*) AS count
  FROM example 
  GROUP BY fruit) AS x 
    ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(e.name, ':', 1) = x.fruit 
ORDER BY x.count DESC, e.id;

+----+------------------------+
| id | name                   |
+----+------------------------+
|  1 | Apple: Color: Yellow   |
|  2 | Apple: Color: Red      |
|  6 | Apple: Color: Yellow   |
|  7 | Apple: Color: Yellow   |
|  3 | Grapes: Color: Green   |
|  4 | Grapes: Color: Green   |
|  5 | Oranges: Color: Orange |
+----+------------------------+
```

Comment: Looking at your answer finally made me understand the convoluted question.